# Rails ApplicationController throwing not found for path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the following in routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, param: :email
  post '/auth/login', to: 'authentication#login'
  get '/*a', to: 'application#not_found'
  get '/attendance/in', to: 'attendances#in'
  get '/attendance/out', to: 'attendances#out'
  get '/user/get_attendance_status', to: 'users#get_attendance_status'
end
```

Now, for example, in my `users_controller.rb` I have the following action:

```
before_action :authorize_request

def get_attendance_status
  render json: { at_work: @current_user.at_work }, status: :ok
end
```

`:authorize_request` is defined in `application_controller.rb` as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    def not_found
        render json: { error: 'not_found' }
    end

    def authorize_request
        header = request.headers['Authorization']
        header = header.split(' ').last if header
        begin
            @decoded = JsonWebToken.decode(header)
            @current_user = User.find(@decoded[:user_id])
            rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
                render json: { errors: e.message }, status: :unauthorized
            rescue JWT::DecodeError => e
                render json: { errors: e.message }, status: :unauthorized
        end
    end
end
```

Now when I submit requests to my local server through Postman, I get the following errors:

```
Started GET "/user/get_attendance_status" for 58.177.56.127 at 2020-05-23 19:12:49 +0800
Processing by ApplicationController#not_found as HTML
  Parameters: {"a"=>"user/get_attendance_status"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 93)


Started GET "/attendance/in" for 58.177.56.127 at 2020-05-23 19:13:14 +0800
Processing by ApplicationController#not_found as HTML
  Parameters: {"a"=>"attendance/in"}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 91)
```

As you can see, the application_controller#not_found is triggered, but why?  I'm not sure why this is occurring. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to move the `get '/*a', to: 'application#not_found'` route to the bottom so my routes.rb now looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, param: :email
  post '/auth/login', to: 'authentication#login'
  get '/attendance/in', to: 'attendances#in'
  get '/attendance/out', to: 'attendances#out'
  get '/user/get_attendance_status', to: 'users#get_attendance_status'
  get '/*a', to: 'application#not_found'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Routes are matched in order of appearance, so yes, your a* routes should be placed at the end. The question is why do you need this route? Rails automatically returns a 404 if the route is not present.

Comment: it returns a json